# Lambda expressions hides compiler errors; how to find them?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, lambda, nancy

Using VS-2012, I observed that if there is an lambda expression and it contains a error, the compiler does not show the actual syntactical error.

Take this example:

```
public class CustomBoostrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        pipelines.BeforeRequest += ctx =>
        {
            if(1=1) //the actual error that needs to be corrected
            return new Response();
        };
    }
}
```

The compiler will report two errors, usually:

```
Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'some type' and 'lambda expression'
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'some type' because it is not a delegate type
```

But it doesn't even bother to report that there is a non-boolean expression in the if() and when corrected, the errors about lambda expressions goes away. The worse thing is that it apparently shows for any kind of compiler error. If one is writing a complex function and make a goof somewhere, they are only left with two very generic errors and must hunt for the actual syntax error (or something similar) within the body. Is there a way to avoid this obfuscation?

Note: this example was noticed when using Nancy framework. I additionally observed that it was not just this particular function but also anywhere else I used a lambda function. At first I thought it was something to do with a compiler but as subsequent comments makes clear, it might not be something to do with the compiler or Visual Studio.

Note #2: I just discovered this only happens with anonymous function. If I define the function and then reference it from the lambda expression instead, the compiler correctly catches the errors within the function.

Comment: Try to fix reported error first, than it should report about `1=1`. It happens this way for me on VS 2015.

Comment: I corrected the typo in my made-up sample but the original point still stands. In VS-2012, it never catches that there is a 1=1. If I correct the error in the body, the code as whole then compiles.

Comment: Could you provide [mcve]? I use C# 5.0 compiler, the one VS 2012 should use, and it always report error to me. For `if(1=1)` it report `Test.cs(x,y): error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer`. For `if(a=1)` it report `Test.cs(x,y): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'`.

Comment: This is now obvious to me that it's not something in general but more likely a problem with a particular method or framework design, of which I am not sure. I updated the sample to include a better sample that can be verified -- unfortunately, this requires Nancy framework because that is where I observe the problem I'm describing and I do not have sufficient expertise to replicate this error without the framework.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question, merely stated an observation about how the compiler works.  You need to actually ask a question.

Comment: Servy - I believe I did... I asked how to ensure that the actual errors within the function body aren't obfuscated by the compiler. From what PetSerAl is saying, it seems that it shouldn't be always the case. It's not yet clear why it wouldn't be in all cases and I don't mind being educated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider this complete answer but I discovered that if I wrote it as non-anonymous function, then the compiler errors show as expected. So, instead of:

```
pipelines.BeforeRequest += ctx =>
    {
        if(1=1) //the actual error that needs to be corrected
        return new Response();
    };
```

Could do this:

```
protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
{
    pipelines.BeforeRequest += ctx => myFunc(ctx);
}

...

private Response myFunc(NancyContext ctx)
{
    if(1=1) //the actual error that needs to be corrected
    return new Response();
};
```

Which then shows the compiler error on the "if(1=1)" as expected. Not as pretty or concise when using anonymous error but at least it's a temporary workaround when debugging a more complex function and it's not immediately obvious where one did it wrong within the body of the function.

Comment: With refactoring tools like Resharper its easy to transform the code between the two.